# hadoop large file does not split

Tags: performance, hadoop, split, mapreduce

I have an input file of size `136MB` and I launched some `WordCount` test and I monitor only one mapper. Then I set `dfs.blocksize` to `64MB` in my `hdfs-site.xml` and I still get one mapper. Am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Changing the `dfs.blocksize` only affects *new* files.

Comment: Can you check how many map slot is available in your cluster and what is the default block size configured in your cluster.

Comment: @RemusRusanu great thank you. Could you post it as a response so I can validate ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `dfs.block.size` is not alone playing a role and it's recommended not
>   to change because it applies globally to HDFS.
>
> Split size in mapreduce is calculated by this formula
>
> ```
> max(mapred.min.split.size, min(mapred.max.split.size, dfs.block.size))
> ```
>
> So you can set these properties in driver class as
>
> ```
> conf.setLong("mapred.max.split.size", maxSplitSize); 
> conf.setLong("mapred.min.split.size", minSplitSize);
> ```
>
> Or in Config file as
>
> ```
> <property>
>     <name>mapred.max.split.size</name>
>     <value>134217728</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>mapred.min.split.size</name>
>     <value>134217728</value>
> </property>
> ```